# In Plotly Express Funnel how do you re-order de y-axis categories?

Tags: python, sorting, plotly, plotly-express

I have a DataFrame with all my data and i have the following stage order

```
order = {0:'NEW',1:'FOLLOW_UP',2:'Demo',3:'QUOTE',4:'CLOSING'}
fig = px.funnel(df, x='count', y='name', color='source',category_orders=order)
```

My DataFrame is perfectly in desired Order as the Order dictionary, but my graph keeps switching positions with QUOTE and DEMO.

It actually makes no difference if category_orders is used or not, tried a bunch of dictionaries styles and arranges but none seem to work.

https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.funnel.html
category_orders (dict with str keys and list of str values (default {})) – By default, in Python 3.6+, the order of categorical values in axes, legends and facets depends on the order in which these values are first encountered in data_frame (and no order is guaranteed by default in Python below 3.6). This parameter is used to force a specific ordering of values per column. The keys of this dict should correspond to column names, and the values should be lists of strings corresponding to the specific display order desired.

[Here is the DataFrame with the issue at the Bottom with Demo and QUOTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Macf7.png)

Check the image of my funnel here
[Funnel with wrong order by plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSHGu.png)

Comment: Can you add your dataframe to the question?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Macf7.png here it is!

Comment: Thanks! If you add as code/text to your question, I'm sure somebody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the issues is caused by the difference how Ploty expects the input data to look like and how your dataframe looks.

Funnel plots seem to expect that all categories present at the end of the funnel are present at each previous stage. Your `Closing` `source` is not present `QUOTE` and your value from `QUOTE` is missing in `Demo`. If you add these two values the order should be correct.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''count name    source
0   NEW IG
2   NEW 0
1   NEW GCLID
1   NEW UTM
1   NEW UTM
1   NEW GCLID
1   NEW GLCID
7   NEW UTM
1   NEW GLCID
1   NEW GCLID
2   NEW 123
1   NEW GCLID
1   NEW GCLID
1   NEW FB
1   NEW FBCLID
1   NEW UTM
1   NEW UTM
1   NEW DATA
1   NEW R
1   NEW GCLID
11  NEW FB
1   NEW FB
7   NEW FB
1   NEW FB
1   NEW GCLID
1   NEW GCLID
1   NEW GCLID
1   FOLLOW_UP   FB
2   FOLLOW_UP   FB
1   FOLLOW_UP   0
1   FOLLOW_UP   IG
1   FOLLOW_UP   FB
1   FOLLOW_UP   FB
1   FOLLOW_UP   FB
2   FOLLOW_UP   123
3   DEMO    FB
1   QUOTE   123
1   QUOTE   123
2   QUOTE   123
3   CLOSING FB'''.splitlines()

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(data)), sep='\t')
px.funnel(df, x='count', y='name', color='source')

# incorrect order
```

[image]
# correct order

```
data.insert(-5, '0\tDEMO\t123')
data.insert(-2, '0\tQUOTE\tFB')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(data)), sep='\t')
px.funnel(df, x='count', y='name', color='source')
```

[image]